# A slight modification of Beta function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, gamma-function, beta-function

The Beta function is defined as follows: for real values $a,b>0$
$$B(a,b) = \int_0^1 w^{a-1}(1-w)^{b-1} dw.$$

It is known that
$$B(a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)},$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.

Is there a way to find a closed expression or bound for the following integral?
$$I:=\int_0^1 w^{a-1}(1-w)^{b-1} e^{-cw} dw,$$
where $c>0$. Of course, one has
$$|I| \leq B(a,b),$$
but I would like to keep an expression in terms of the exponential of $c$. ($c$ will be some $x^2$ which should then be an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$, that is why).

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: I added some further manipulations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Taylor series for the exponential and get

$$\int_0^1 w^{a-1}(1-w)^{b-1}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-c)^k}{k!}w^k\ \text{d}w$$

Which becomes

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-c)^k}{k!}\int_0^1 w^{a-1+k}(1-w)^{b-1}\ \text{d}w$$

The integral can be computed easily, and gives

$$\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a+b+k)}$$

which is nothing but the Beta

$$B(b, a, k)$$

hence in the end you have

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-c)^k}{k!}\ B(b, a, k)$$

**Further Manipulations**

Since $B(a, b, k)$ is expressed as we wrote above, you can take out the first Gamma term which does not depend on $k$ and get a familiar result:

$$\Gamma(b)\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-c)^k}{k!}\frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a+b+k)}$$

The series can be summed into The so called HyperGeometric Function:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-c)^k}{k!}\frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a+b+k)} = \frac{\Gamma (a) \, _1F_1(a;a+b;-c)}{\Gamma (a+b)}$$

Hence the final result is:

$$\Gamma(b)\frac{\Gamma (a) \, _1F_1(a;a+b;-c)}{\Gamma (a+b)}$$

We again recognize a Beta, so finally:

$$\boxed{ B(a, b)\, _1F_1(a;a+b;-c)}$$

Comment: Aren't there nicer expression for the $F$-function? like, bounds in terms of a function in $c$ which is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @Martingalo You can check for the definition of the HyperGeometrid Function, but you will find it's expressed as a series. There are many notable values, according to simplifications like $c = 0$ (trivial) or things like that. The general form is however defines as a series, so you won't find a solution in terms of pure exponentials.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following integral defintion of the [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function)
\begin{equation}
{}_{1}\mathrm{F}_{1}(\alpha ; \beta ;x) 
= \frac{\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta - \alpha)} \int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-z)^{\beta - \alpha -1} z^{\alpha -1} \mathrm{e}^{xz} dz
\end{equation}
for $\mathrm{Re}\,\alpha \gt \mathrm{Re}\,\beta \gt 0$, we have $a=\alpha \,,\, b = \beta - \alpha \,,\, -c=x$
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\,{}_{1}\mathrm{F}_{1}(a;a+b;-c) \\
&= \mathrm{B}(a,b)\,{}_{1}\mathrm{F}_{1}(a;a+b;-c)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since $c>0$, $\mathrm{e}^{-c w}$ is convex for $w \in [0,1]$.  So replace $\mathrm{e}^{-c w}$ with its average value of the line through its endpoints on the interval, $\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathrm{e}^{0}+\mathrm{e}^{-c})$.  That is, 
$$  I < \frac{1}{2}(1+\mathrm{e}^{-c}) B(a,b)  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score -1):

According to Maple, it is

$$ \eqalign{ \Gamma \left( a \right) &{{\rm e}^{-c/2}}{c}^{-a/2-1-b/2}\Gamma
 \left( b \right)  \cr&\frac{\left(  \left( 1+a \right)  \left( b+a \right) {
{M}_{a/2-b/2+1,\,b/2+a/2+1/2}\left(c\right)}+b{{ M}_{a/2-b/2,\,
b/2+a/2+1/2}\left(c\right)} \left( c+a+b \right)  \right) }{\Gamma
 \left( b+a+2 \right) }}
$$

Where $M$ is the Whittaker M function.